# How do I call a function on multiple ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that formats a range but it only seems to be formatting the first range I select.

I've tried selecting the range first then formatting but it lengthens my code quite a bit.

```
Sub Numbers()

    Call format(Range(Cells(4, "A"), Cells(2 + i - j, "AA")))

    Call format(Range(Cells(4, "C"), Cells(4 + i - j, "F")))

    Call format(Range(Cells(4, "G"), Cells(4 + i - j, "J")))

End Sub

Sub format(R As Range)

    With R
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .weight = xlMedium
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

I want to format all the ranges but its only formatting the first one ie: only formats -> `Range(Cells(4, "A"), Cells(2 + i - j, "AA"))`

Comment: We will need to see more of the code, as well as the format sub.

Comment: you will need to show the loop.  `i` and `j` are `0`  Also the other two ranges are inside `Range(Cells(4, "A"), Cells(2 + i - j, "AA")))`

Comment: Delete `Selection` - you are working with `R`, not with a selection

Answer (score 0):

You could either loop through in your main sub and call the `format` sub x amount of times or modify the `format` sub to use a `ParamArray`. This will allow you to pass any number of ranges to the `format` sub in one line

```
Sub formatRange(ParamArray rngs() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(rngs)
        If TypeName(rngs(i)) = "Range" Then
            With rngs(i)
                Debug.Print i, .Address, TypeName(rngs(i))

                .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
                .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
                With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub test()
    formatRange Range("A1"), Range("A2"), Range("A3")
    formatRange Range("B5"), Range("I6")
    ' etc. etc....
End Sub
```